# Tengo un problema con calculos de credito en formulario

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de hacer el siguiente calculo:

El usuario ingresa su salario.
El sistema calcula sobre su sueldo un 30% de credito.
El sistema le otorga el 30% de su sueldo mas el 33% de interes.

Ejemplo: Si yo tengo un salario de $1000, el sistema me otorga $300 de crédito y el total que debo pagar es de $399, ya que $99 es de interés que es el 33%.

Tome un ejemplo de un código, pero no se como adaptarlo y solo me muestra los intereses en el formulario, también comente el elemento click porque no es necesario un click, pero tampoco me muestra los resultado y no se como arreglarlo.

Hice varios cambios y me da este error: `TypeError: inporteOtorgado.forEach is not a function`

Gracias.

```js
inporteOtorgado.forEach((elemento) => {
  elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (importeSueldo.value == "") {
     console.log("Falta el valor de tu inversión")
    } else {
      let calculoUno = importeSueldo * 30 / 100
      let inporteOtorgado = calculoUno * 33 / 100
   let calculoFinal = Number(calculoUno) + Number(calculoDOs)
   importeDevolucion.value = calculoFinal
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="">
Mi sueldo: <input type="text" name="" id="importeSueldo">
<p>
Te otorgamos (30%): <input type="text" name="inporteOtorgado" value="" id="inporteOtorgado">
</p>
A devolver en un pago (33%): <input type="text" name="" id="importeDevolucion">

<p>
<input type="submit" name="" id="" value="Enviar">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Entonces ¿la duda es como completar los demás inputs con los valores calculados?

Comment: Claro, pero ahora estoy teniendo mas problemas cada vez que toco algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puntos a mencionar:

- No veo por que uses un ciclo, pues no tienes varios elementos que iterar ya que la idea es obtener el valor del sueldo y a partir de ese generar los dos valores restantes; entonces podemos prescindir de este proceso por completo

Precisamente por lo anterior es que obtienes este mensaje de error:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: inporteOtorgado.forEach is not a function",

- Si tratas de hacer 2 cálculos a la vez entonces lo más simple sería agregarle un listener al evento que quieras disparar por ejemplo cada que el usuario teclee valores en el importe sueldo
- Además podemos dividir las operaciones en 2 y agregarlas a sus respectivos inputs, así por cada vez que el usuario teclee ambos valores se irán calculado
- Removí el botón de enviar y así entonces el usuario no podrá obtener un valor hasta que no teclee su sueldo

**CÓDIGO**

```html
    <form action="">
    Mi sueldo: <input type="text" name="" id="importeSueldo">
    <p>
    Te otorgamos (30%): <input type="text" name="inporteOtorgado" value="" id="inporteOtorgado">
    </p>
    A devolver en un pago (33%): <input type="text" name="" id="importeDevolucion">
    
    </form>
    
    <script>
    let importeSueldo = document.getElementById("importeSueldo")
    let inporteOtorgado = document.getElementById("inporteOtorgado")
    let importeDevolucion = document.getElementById("importeDevolucion")
        
    importeSueldo.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
      let operacionUno = 30 * Number(importeSueldo.value) / 100
      inporteOtorgado.value = operacionUno
      let operacionDos = operacionUno + (33 * Number(operacionUno) / 100)
      importeDevolucion.value = operacionDos
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Gracias BetaM, tu haces que deje de odiar JavaScript. Fue muy claro. Igualmente veo que tu código es muy pero muy actual. Lo note por como declaras las variables.

Answer (score 1):

Removí el forEach() por una función llamada `calcular()` que se llama al presionar el botón enviar.

```js
let importeSueldo = document.getElementById("importeSueldo")
let inporteOtorgado = document.getElementById("inporteOtorgado")
let importeDevolucion = document.getElementById("importeDevolucion")
    
function calcular(){
    if (importeSueldo.value == "") {
     console.log("Falta el valor de tu inversión")
    } else {
       let teOtorgamos = importeSueldo.value * 30 / 100
       let aDevolver = teOtorgamos * (1 + 33/100)
       
       inporteOtorgado.value = teOtorgamos;
       importeDevolucion.value = aDevolver;
       }
  
}
```

```html
<form action="">
Mi sueldo: <input type="text" name="" id="importeSueldo">
<p>
Te otorgamos (30%): <input type="text" name="inporteOtorgado" value="" id="inporteOtorgado">
</p>
A devolver en un pago (33%): <input type="text" name="" id="importeDevolucion">

<p>
<input type="button" name="" id="" onclick="calcular()" value="Enviar">
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias Lobos. Tambien me sirvio. Un mismo resultado, dos modelos distintos!